# How do I get pandas to plot in interactive mode?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've managed to get it working with this code:

```
%env DISPLAY=:20
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.switch_backend('Qt5Agg')
# %pylab
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

(opens window with graph in interactive mode)

but not with pandas code:

```
%env DISPLAY=:20
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
plt.switch_backend('Qt5Agg')
pd.Series(10,index=list(range(0,10))).plot()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I am- but I don't want it inline- I want to open with Qt5Agg

Comment: In the second version using pandas, you don't call `plt.show()`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: any solution on this?